# Hiding ip address when using coinomi wallet

Tags: android, vpn, mobile, ip, tor

How do I hide my ip address if I use a wallet as coinomi? Do I have to use Orbot? If yes, what exactly should I do? (I'm using it from an android) I just want to have privacy when I log into the wallet. I want to hide my ip when logging into it.

Comment: First of all you can't hide an IP address. You could connect from another source (open WiFi (not safe), public WiFi (not safe) or a VPN) that is different from your home WiFi or 3/4/5G connection and use that to connect to your wallet. I'm not sure what your privacy concern is here but by just using a different IP is not going to matter much. Think about all your applications, such as Gmail or social media accounts, that will connect using your credentials. Correlation of data could still disclose it was you connecting to your wallet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your personal IP from Coinomi itself, you can use a proxy or VPN on your device, or connect to the internet using a wifi/4g connection that is not your personal one. If you have a Bitcoin ElectrumX server, you can also point your BTC wallet in the app to it, so your wallet information comes from your own server. Coinomi is already an anonymous wallet, however. No user information is collected or transmitted, IPs aren't logged on transactions.

If you want to hide your IP from other participants on the Bitcoin network, you don't have to do anything. Transactions you send from the app are relayed by Coinomi's servers. Network observers monitoring transactions will see all transactions coming from Coinomi's IP, so the user's IP is always hidden.

You can read more about Coinomi's privacy features here: https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000030207-what-are-coinomi-s-privacy-features-